# Differential GPS

Tags: localization, gps

I want to use DGPS on a robot. I understand how DGPS works but I am having trouble figuring out what specific hardware I need. Is there a good resource for how to actually setup DGPS? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need the following:

1. A target DGPS-capable unit
2. A source DGPS unit
3. A data link to carry the differential data from source to target

and of course necessary software and cabling.

You can find several white papers and application notes on manufacturers' internet pages. One of them is the following : [trimble](http://www.trimble.com/gps_tutorial/dgps-how.aspx)

A poor man's DGPS setup could be experimented, where you simply use two GPS Receivers and use the difference to correct the target GPS pos. This would not technically be as accurate as the complete DGPS solution. But, for hobby purposes this would probably be enough (not sure, never tried).